# HOW TO get an overloaded private/protected method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Reflection        
{
    class Test
    {
        protected void methodname(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(("in the world of the reflection- only i"));
            Console.Read();
        }    
        protected void methodname(int i, int j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(("in the world of the reflection  i , j"));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            BindingFlags eFlags = BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            Test aTest = new Test();
            MethodInfo mInfoMethod = typeof(Reflection.Test).GetMethod("methodname", eFlags);
            mInfoMethod.Invoke(aTest, new object[] { 10 ,20});   
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call both  Getmethod() overloaded methods. If i give the method name , an runtime error is thrown(ambigous method call) . How to avoid this and how each method can be called.

Comment: You can't call both overloads with a single `Invoke()` call. You have to `Invoke()` each one separately.

Comment: how to invoke each method seperately?

Comment: Just call `Invoke()` two times?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to pass types of your overloaded method, this is how reflection sorts out your desired method when there's a overload.

You can't call both the methods as it has different types of input parameter. You have to know exactly which one you exactly want to call, and pass along a `Type[]`, for instance:

```
// invoking overload with two parameters
MethodInfo mInfoMethod =
    typeof(Reflection.Test).GetMethod(
        "methodname",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        Type.DefaultBinder,
        new[] {typeof (int), typeof (int)},
        null);

mInfoMethod.Invoke(aTest, new object[] { 10 ,20});
```

**OR**

```
// invoking overload with one parameters
MethodInfo mInfoMethod =
    typeof(Reflection.Test).GetMethod(
        "methodname",
        vBindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        Type.DefaultBinder,
        new[] { typeof (int) },
        null);

mInfoMethod.Invoke(aTest, new object[] { 10 });
```

Comment: Tried the suggest way: intention to call overload method accepting two parameters.But getmethod() returns null value.

Comment: Well, you can't call protected method, consider making it public

Comment: I have updated the code to call protected method using reflection. Please check now

Answer (score 5):

Use 'GetMethods' instead to retrieve all the overloads, then pick the ones you want.

Comment: GetMethods doesn't retrieve inherited protected methods for example.

Comment: It does by setting the right BindingFlags: `type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))`

Answer (score 1):

Please find a working sample below:

```
public class ReflectionSample
    {
        protected void Method(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("in the world of the reflection- only {0}", i));
            Console.Read();
        }
        protected void Method(int i, int j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("in the world of the reflection  {0} , {1}", i,j));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var eFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var objType = Type.GetType("Sample.ReflectionSample");
            var methods = objType.GetMethods(eFlags);
            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
                if (method.Name == "Method")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Method name is :" + method.Name);
                    var parameters = method.GetParameters();
                    int value = 10;
                    List<object> param = new List<object>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        param.Add(value * 5);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(parameters.Count());
                    method.Invoke(new ReflectionSample(), param.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just added the if condition on method.Name to filter it down to invoke only the desired methods.

Comment: I tried the sample application, the Getmethods throws an exception

Comment: I just got it working and then posted the sample. Can you tell me what is the exception its throwing. Also make sure that your projects build properties has .NET 4.0 as framework and not .NET 4.0 client profile. Also run Vs.Net under admin privileges. What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Also note that the namespace of the class ReflectionSample is "Sample" hence the GetMethods has the complete path of the class --> Namespace.ClassName

Comment: i am using 3.5 .net version and i am getting the exception object : NullReferenceException unhandled. {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: intitally i was getting the compilation error : i changed the parameters.count to parameters.length and included the namespace.

Comment: I changed my framework to 3.5 and tested the same code and it works without any errors.

Answer (score -1):

can u try like this

You have to specify which method you want:

```
class SomeType 
{
    void Foo(int size, string bar) { }
    void Foo() { }
}

SomeType obj = new SomeType();
// call with int and string arguments
obj.GetType().GetMethod("Foo", new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string)).Invoke(obj, new object[] { 42, "Hello" });
// call without arguments
obj.GetType().GetMethod("Foo", new Type[0]).Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```